# Cannot find javaw on eclipse to run hello world

Tags: java, eclipse, javaw

This is some strange and annoying issue i am facing .
I was just going through some issue and decided to write simple program to solve it.
It seems that eclipse cannot execute "hello world" 
and this is the error message I get

```
Exception occurred executing command line. Cannot run program ""\"C:\Program
Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe\""" (in directory "D:\Vishal_j2E\HelloWorld")
CreateProcess error=3, The system cannot find the path specified
```

Notice the javaw.exe path.

Then I copied the Java folder to D: (may be something to do with space between program file) and in eclipse

```
 Windows>Preference>Java>Installed Jres
```

added the D: path to it. Still I have the same issue except for the path has changed from C: to D:

```
 Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program ""\"D:\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe\""" 
(in directory "D:\Vishal_j2E\HelloWorld"): CreateProcess error=3, 
The system cannot find the path specified
```

What seems confusing to me is  **"\"** before both path. I believe this may be the actual issue but i couldn't find anything to solve it

PS: My Android and Java EE apps work fine. and yes execution through command line also works

Edit 1:
1.Using Juno

2.this is what I get from

%PATH%
C:\Python33\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;D:\android-
sdk-windows\tools;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin; 
**`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin;`**
D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Mercurial;C:\Progra
m Files\Apache-Subversion-1.7.2\bin;E:\Vishal\sw\dex2jar-0.0.7.11-SNAPSHOT\dex2j
ar-0.0.7.11-SNAPSHOT;C:\Program Files\bin\repo;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\TomSe
rve\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\bin;D:\Maven\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin

%JAVA_HOME%

**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an actual answer but rather the last resort.
I had to re-setup my development environment
That includes fresh Java installation, Environment Variables and Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

open `eclipse.ini`

and change the following line

```
-vmargs

to include path to your javaw.exe
```

save and restart eclipse it should work

Comment: where is your java installation located

Comment: please see edit 1. I still have a bad feeling about "\" and multiple """

Answer (score 0):

I guess in eclipse instalation folder eclipse.ini file will be there.
In this file need to change java instalation path.

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin/javaw.exe
```

change this to your java instalation directory.